# No identifier/primary key specified for Entity, ORM Doctrine

Tags: php, orm, doctrine

What I try to do is to have two classes User in one file and Video in another. My task is to do database where user have to login and after that he can upload video. The video have entity $uploaded_by and there should go $id from the User class.

User.php:

```
<?php
// src/User.php
namespace Db;
use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;
use Doctrine\Common\Collections\ArrayCollection;


/**
 * @ORM\Entity @ORM\Table(name="user")
 **/
class User
{
/**@ORM\Id @ORM\Column(type="integer") **/
protected $id;

/** @ORM\Column(type="string") **/
protected $name;

/** @ORM\Column(type="datetime") **/
protected $created_at;

/** @ORM\Column(type="datetime", nullable=true) **/
protected $last_login;
```

Video.php:

```
<?php
// src/Video.php
namespace Db;
use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;
use Doctrine\Common\Collections\ArrayCollection;


/**
 * @ORM\Entity @ORM\Table(name="video")
 **/
class Video
{
/** @ORM\Id @ORM\Column(type="integer") @ORM\GeneratedValue **/
protected $id;

/** @ORM\Column(type="string") **/
protected $name;

/** @ORM\Column(type="datetime") **/
protected $created_at;

/**
 * @OneToOne(targetEntity="User")
 * @JoinColumn(name="user_id", referencedColumnName="id")
 * @ORM\Column(type="integer") **/
protected $uploaded_by;

/** @ORM\Column(type="integer", nullable=true) **/
protected $deleted;
```

When I try to update ORM schema in Doctrine with

```
$ vendor/bin/doctrine orm:schema-tool:update --force --dump-sql
```

The result is:

```
In MappingException.php line 52:

No identifier/primary key specified for Entity "Db\User". Every Entity 
must  
have an identifier/primary key.
```

1. What am I doing wrong?
2. If I there is something wrong with connection of classes how can I fix it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

try to change this:

```
/**@ORM\Id @ORM\Column(type="integer") **/
protected $id;
```

to this:

```
/**
 * @var int
 *
 * @ORM\Column(name="id", type="integer")
 * @ORM\Id
 * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="IDENTITY")
 */
protected $id;
```

Comment: In AnnotationException.php line 54:
                                                                               
  [Semantical Error] The annotation "@OneToOne" in property Db\Video::$upload  
  ed_by was never imported. Did you maybe forget to add a "use" statement for  
   this annotation?

Comment: you need to change @OneToOne to @ORM\OneToOne